# Kerbal Space Program saved game not showing up in File Explorer

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I want to copy some of my crafts from one save to another. However, I can't seem to find the save in File Explorer. The save shows up in the game itself, but not in file explorer. Same thing with "parts", there is nothing in it, but all the parts show up in the game. There are only 3 things right now in the "save" directory in KSP_win64, which are default, training, and scenarios. default is indeed one of my saves, yet it's my career mode save with nothing in it, because I don't play career mode. I play most in my sandbox save, called "BOB", yet I can't find it anywhere in the KSP directory. Any idea where to find your saved games in File Explorer?

I don't have the steam version; I have the version from the KSP website.

Comment: Are those files hidden in (through) Windows?

Comment: The "saves" folder is where they *should* be. If they're not… I dunno. Just to check the obvious, have you tried [using the search feature in your OS](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/chfind.htm)? The save folder should have the same name on disk as it has in the game (except with some special characters replaced with underscores, I think).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find your craft from your game, you will have to go to your Kerbal Space Program folder. Inside it you will see 2 folders, click the one that is called Kerbal Space Program.
[image]

Once you open the folder you will find more folders, click the ships folder.
[image]

Once you open that folder there will be an SPH and VAB folder, inside those folders are your crafts.

Comment: Those ships are the default ships that come with sandbox mode. They don't include your custom ships.

Comment: Ok, I found where you can find the crafts you made, don't click on the ships file, click on the saves file, and click your game file (it should be between your scenarios and training file, and in your game file, you will see your ships :)